# Travis-CI does not use oraclejdk8

Tags: travis-ci

I have this configuration in the .Travis.yml file, but Travis-CI still runs in Java 1.7. How can this problem be solved?

```
language: java 
jdk: 
   - oraclejdk8
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to container-based infrastructure. For now it doesn't provide "oraclejdk8". I found the issue reading this post: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/2313

To solve the problem avoid the use container-based infrastructure using **sudo: required**

```
# enable build for java8 - not working with container-based infrastructure for now
sudo: required
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

For more information about container-based infrastructure read:

- http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/?utm_source=legacy-notice&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=legacy-upgrade
- http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure/

To avoid other problems I suggest you to validate your file using http://lint.travis-ci.org/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't know if this works. I tried many different options, but I couldn't solve the issue. Someone else solved it, although nobody (himself including) knows what caused the problem. We guess it was an issue with line-ending format, but we are not sure about that. Anyhow, it works. Thanks for the help!